# Can't access an object pointer even though its hasnt been deleted

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, c++11, crash

My program crashes every time it gets to the `render(Mesh* mesh)` function, it works fine if i just have a `std::cout` in it but not when I try and access the the pointers in the `RenderingEngine` class. I have put `cout`s in the destructors of camera and window and they are not called, and the render function is called only after the `RenderingEngine` has been constructed so im not sure why it wont let me access the pointers

The error it gives me is this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0101F722 in GameCreatorEngine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

```
#include "RenderingEngine.h"
#include "ShaderManager.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Mesh.h"


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

RenderingEngine::RenderingEngine(WindowEngine* window)
{
    this->window = window;
    main_camera = new Camera(window->getWidth() / window->getHeight(), 100.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    shaders     = new ShaderManager();
    bound_program = shaders->getProgram(shaders->DEFAULT);
    window->setCursorVisability(false);

    cout << "renderer created" << endl;
}


RenderingEngine::~RenderingEngine()
{
    delete main_camera;
    delete shaders;
    delete window;

    cout << "renderer deleted" << endl;
}

void RenderingEngine::setCamera(Camera* camera)
{
    main_camera = camera;
}

ShaderProgram* RenderingEngine::getBoundProgram()
{
    return bound_program;
}

void RenderingEngine::render(Mesh* mesh)
{
    if (main_camera == nullptr) // crashes
    {
        cout << "weeeeeeeeeeeeeyl" << endl;
    } 

    main_camera->print(); // crashes

    window->clearScreen(); // crashes

    window->swapBuffer(); // crashes

    cout << "WHY IS THIS WORKING" << endl; // works

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // WORKS


}

void RenderingEngine::render(ShaderProgram* program, Mesh* mesh)
{
    window->clearScreen();
    {
        glUseProgram(program->getProgramID());
        glBindVertexArray(*mesh->getVAO_ID());

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        {
            main_camera->update(window);
            program->addUniform4m("mvp", main_camera->getModelViewProjection(main_camera->getTransformationMatrix()));

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, *mesh->getIndicesCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        }
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
    window->swapBuffer();
}
```

-

```
#pragma once
#include <glew.h>
#include "GameObject.h"

class Mesh;
class Camera;
class ShaderManager;
class ShaderProgram;
class WindowEngine;

class RenderingEngine
{
public:
    RenderingEngine(WindowEngine* window);
    ~RenderingEngine();

    void setCamera(Camera* cam);
    ShaderProgram* getBoundProgram();

    void render(Mesh* mesh);
    void render(ShaderProgram* program, Mesh* mesh);

private:
    Camera* main_camera;
    WindowEngine* window;

    ShaderManager* shaders;
    ShaderProgram* bound_program;
};
```

Comment: Probably because you're deleting `window`, and you don't own it. Also if you copy or assign `RenderingEngine`, everything will collapse in a heap. Think about what happens to the pointers when you copy or assign.

Comment: i added a cout in the window destructor and its not being called

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would actually run something that could crash, let alone print to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's crashing on `if (main_camera == nullptr) // crashes`, then it's because "this" is null.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your RenderingEngine pointer is nullptr

Answer (score 0):

looks like i miss this-> out

```
void GameObject::setRenderingEngine(RenderingEngine* renderer) 
{
        renderer = renderer; // assigning to self
}
```